# One particular PC slows down the whole network

Tags: networking, windows-10, connection

I built and added a new desktop PC to a network.
Said PC has a Gigabyte z170x- gaming 3 rev 1.1 motherboard.

I installed Windows 10 from scratch, and for some reason it didn't detect any ethernet ports. So I went and downloaded the LAN Driver (Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller) from the manufacturer's page.

It installed just fine, but as soon as I plug an ethernet cable into the motherboard, the resource manager shows it's receiving information at a 3.0 Mbps rate, rendering internet connection to the whole network unusable. This happens as soon as it boots up, and like I said, it's running a fresh install, so there is no malware or P2P software running in the background.

This doesn't happen when I connect any other computer to the same port.

What could be causing this?

Comment: OK. Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, done now

Comment: Your interwebs are hax0red! Can you run tcpdump or wireshark on another system on the local network? That would tell you what kind of traffic is going nuts. Most likely, because it's a new system, it's downloading a zillion patches, and because the net card is fast and assuming the patch provider is fast, you get a swamped network connection. Does windows allow you to throttle the update downloader? Just a guess though.

Comment: Could it be downloading Windows Updates?

Comment: Just checked, most of the traffic is coming from 13.107.4.50.  According to ipaddress.com it belongs to Microsoft Corporation in Redmond, Washington, United States. Weird, if it's downloading patches then the process is running completely on the background, the update section doesn't show any download in progress
Didn't think that windows updates could be the culprit, since this never happened to me before, plus any attempt to run Microsoft Edge freezes the computer (thought it was the Network Adapter going nuts, not a regular download)
Will leave it overnight and come back with the results

Answer (score 0):

TCP's built-in congestion control algorithms should prevent any one host from hogging all the Internet bandwidth and starving out all the other devices. If one host downloading at 3Mbps makes the whole network unusable, TCP congestion control probably isn't working. By far the most common cause of that is a very common router bug called bufferbloat.

To address bufferbloat, enable a smart queueing algorithm such as FQ-CoDel (or plain CoDel, or PIE) on your router. Most factory firmware doesn't have this, so you may have to install something line OpenWrt or DD-WRT on your router.

There's a product called IQrouter that is a turn-key solution for this, for people who want an easy solution. IQrouter is not only bufferbloat-free itself, but it employs a nifty trick to keep other devices on your network from exhibiting bufferbloat behavior as well.